# Foreach  не работает с массивом.- не понимаю - новичок ищет помощи

Tags: html, php

```
<form method='post' action='' >
Название работы:<SELECT name='namelab'><OPTION value='_name[]'>name1
<OPTION value='_name[]'>name2<OPTION value='_name[]'>name3<OPTION value='_name[]'>name4</SELECT>
</form>

<?
$mena=$_POST["_name"];
foreach ($mena as $key=>$value) {
    print "{$key}: {$value}<br/>"; }
?>
```

Notice: Undefined index: _name in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\g\php.php on line 9

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\g\php.php on line 10

Comment: php подсказывает Вам "Notice: Undefined index: _name". То есть, по какой то причине нет ключа `_name` в `$_POST`. А вот почему, это уже попробуйте разобраться сами. Но дам подсказку. Воспользуйтесь функциями `print_r` или `var_dump` и распечатайте значение переменной `$_POST`. Узнаете много интересного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тут бред написан

```
<SELECT name='namelab'><OPTION value='_name[]'>name1
<OPTION value='_name[]'>name2<OPTION value='_name[]'>name3<OPTION value='_name[]'>name4</SELECT>
```

поменяйте  на

```
<SELECT name='_name'>
    <OPTION value='name1'>name1</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='name2'>name2</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='name3'>name3</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='name4'>name4</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: Я, конечно, за чистоту и правильность кода, но если под бредом вы имели ввиду отсутствие закрывающего тега, а не значения атрибутов `value`, то вы [не очень правы](http://htmlbook.ru/html/option).

Comment: проблема в обработчике=\

Comment: под бредом я понимаю значение value

Answer (score 0):

А вы хоть несколько вариантов выбираете?
Потому что foreach дает такую ошибку только тогда когда ему суют не массив. 
Вот прочитайте - http://htmlbook.ru/html/select/multiple
И для профилирования работы, пробуйте вначале выводить все что присылается, это значительно упростит задачу. 
Удачи!